# How to set BLE device address type to "random" for advertisement

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, bluez

I was trying to set the BLE peripheral device's (CSR 4.0) address type to random so that its advertisement packets include different MAC addresses. Any help regarding this would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean programmatically or from the command line? From the command line you can use:-

```
$hciconfig hci0 lerandaddr <bdaddr>
```

If you want to change that programmatically, then have a look at the source code for the above function:-

```
static void cmd_le_addr(int ctl, int hdev, char *opt)
{
}
```

This can be found in the hciconfig.c file [here](https://github.com/pauloborges/bluez/blob/master/tools/hciconfig.c#L198).